# Php 7.1 preg_replace заменяет указанные символы

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, replace

```
preg_replace("/[^a-zA-ZА-Яа-я0-9\s]/", "", $string)
```

Задаю вот такой код в PHP чтобы убрал все кроме букв и цифр, а в инпуте пишу например **Геральт ++[.** а вместо того чтобы вывести просто **Геральт** без лишних символов, PHP выводит Ге�ал�� Обясните пожалуйста где ошибка

Comment: в конце добавь `/u` вместо просто `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace("/[^a-zA-ZА-Яа-я0-9\s]/ui", "", $string)
```

В вашем случае надо было просто добавить `ui`. /u - поддержка юникода, i - игнор регистра букв (что не обязательно, для работы достаточно и флага /u)

Comment: Большое спасибо за то что помогли мне и другми